# Is there any difference between docker-compose up and docker run?

Tags: fastapi, gunicorn, uvicorn

I'm trying to set up an image and container using nginx, gunicorn, with FastAPI app using unicorn.

This is my base app which is called test.py

```
from routers import healthcheck, waterfall

app = FastAPI()
app.include_router(waterfall.router)
app.include_router(healthcheck.router)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Hello Test")
```

My dockerfile is just this for now:

```
# Start with a lightweight base image
FROM tiangolo/uvicorn-gunicorn:python3.11-slim AS base

RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y upgrade

# Copy only necessary files
WORKDIR /app
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
COPY src .
```

When I run docker run following the [offical image](https://github.com/tiangolo/uvicorn-gunicorn-fastapi-docker#app_module) instructions:

```
docker run -p 80:80 -e MODULE_NAME="test" test
```

I can access my endpoints normally.

when I do docker compose:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
    tensor:
        build: app
        environment:
            - MODULE_NAME = "test"
        ports:
          - "80:80"
        container_name: test
```

all I get is "Hello world! From Uvicorn with Gunicorn. Using Python 3.11"

Wouldn't the 2 different formats result in the same thing?

Answer (score 2):

**yes**

**docker-run** starts the container from a single docker image.
you can specify the name of the container, and the image to use.

**docker-compose up** starts the multiple container defined in docker-compose.yml file. it is the command to start and managed multi-container docker application.